# После обновления dpkg вызывает конфигурирование grub, которое завершается с ошибкой

Tags: linux, linux-mint, grub, apt, dpkg

После очередного apt-get upgrade и apt-get autoremove на Mint 19 оказалось, что dpkg не смог настроить пакет с обновлением образа оси. Точнее, не смог удалить старый linux-image-4.15.0-66-generic. Когда запустил upgrade ещё раз, вывел вот это:

```
Чтение списков пакетов… Готово
Построение дерева зависимостей       
Чтение информации о состоянии… Готово
Расчёт обновлений… Готово
Следующий пакет устанавливался автоматически и больше не требуется:
  shim
Для его удаления используйте «sudo apt autoremove».
Следующие пакеты будут УДАЛЕНЫ:
  linux-image-4.15.0-66-generic
Следующие пакеты будут оставлены в неизменном виде:
  fwupd fwupdate fwupdate-signed linux-generic linux-headers-generic linux-image-generic
Следующие пакеты будут обновлены:
  code linux-base
Обновлено 2 пакетов, установлено 0 новых пакетов, для удаления отмечено 1 пакетов, и 6 пакетов не обновлено.
Установлено или удалено не до конца 5 пакетов.
Необходимо скачать 0 B/62,3 MB архивов.
После данной операции объём занятого дискового пространства уменьшится на 8 394 kB.
Хотите продолжить? [Д/н] y
Предварительная настройка пакетов ...
(Чтение базы данных … на данный момент установлено 410706 файлов и каталогов.)
Удаляется linux-image-4.15.0-66-generic (4.15.0-66.75) …
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Deleting /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-66-generic
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub:
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/50_linuxmint.cfg'
Генерируется файл настройки grub …
Найден образ linux: /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-76-generic
Найден образ initrd: /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-76-generic
Найден образ linux: /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-72-generic
Найден образ initrd: /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-72-generic
Найден образ linux: /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-70-generic
Найден образ initrd: /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-70-generic
Найден образ linux: /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-20-generic
Найден образ initrd: /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-20-generic
Найден образ linux: /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-76-generic
Найден образ initrd: /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-76-generic
Найден образ linux: /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-72-generic
Найден образ initrd: /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-72-generic
Найден образ linux: /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-70-generic
Найден образ initrd: /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-70-generic
Найден образ linux: /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-20-generic
Найден образ initrd: /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-20-generic
Добавление записи в загрузочное меню для конфигурации с микропрограммой EFI
ошибка: syntax error.
ошибка: Incorrect command.
ошибка: syntax error.
Синтаксическая ошибка в строке 138
В сгенерированном файле настроек GRUB обнаружены синтаксические ошибки.
Убедитесь, что в файлах /etc/default/grub
и /etc/grub.d/* ошибки отсутствуют или пошлите сообщение об ошибке
в прикреплённым файлом /boot/grub/grub.cfg.new.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 1
dpkg: ошибка при обработке пакета linux-image-4.15.0-66-generic (--remove):
 installed linux-image-4.15.0-66-generic package post-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1
При обработке следующих пакетов произошли ошибки:
 linux-image-4.15.0-66-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Сконфигурировал граб вручную с grub-mkconfig, но dpkg упрорно делал по своему. Когда посмотрел 138 строчку его сгенерированного конфига, там было так:

```
### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/40_custom_proxy ###
menuentry "Linux Mint" --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-simple-f034ca3a-4301-49a0-8ca3-148874a7e419' {
}  # ЭТО 138 СТРОКА
### END /etc/grub.d/40_custom_proxy ###
```

Подозреваю, шо в блоке фигурных скобок должны быть какие-то указания, как в других блоках, но как их получить? Файл /etc/default/grub без комментариев выглядит так:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT="0"
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE="hidden"
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR="`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

А /ect/default/grub.d//etc/default/grub.d/50_linuxmint.cfg так:

```
set -e
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR="Ubuntu"
```

Прэкол в том, шо теперь dpkg пытается удалить старый линусячий образ при любой операции apt, будь то обновление, удаление или установка, так шо я не могу теперь вообще воспользоваться менеджером пакетов. Можно хотя бы как то заставить dpkg забыть об этом образе и не пытаться конфигурировать grub? Мне граб по сути не нужен, комп загружает сразу раздел с линуксом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разобрался. Попробовал удалить вообще файл /etc/grub.d/40_custom_proxy, чтобы он не копировался в конфиг, помогло, dpkg сдвинулся с мёртвой точки и всё обновил. После перезагрузки Mint загрузился нормально, но загрузчик ругнулся вот так:

```
ошибка: не удалось найти команду "hwmatch".
Загружается Linix 4.15.0-76-generic ...
Загружается начальный виртуальный диск ...
```

В принципе, было всё равно, но чтобы устранить все неполадки, полностью переустановил grub, благо теперь apt-get стал доступен. Теперь grub тоже запускается из своего раздела, причём имеет в списке удалённый ранее Mint. Вопрос закрыт.